# Collect all the String before the first delim in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I needed to collect all the data before the first pipe form a SQL server Table.

```
table ( input )
url
---------------------------
www.abcd.com | ww.asd.com
google.com | www.google.com
yahoo.com
```

what i want (output)

```
url
------------
www.abcd.com
google.com
yahoo.com
```

What i've tried:

```
 substring( url, 0 ,charindex('|' , url) )
```

This above code is omitting all the url that doesn't have a pipe. How can i incorporate the change of not omitting strings that doesn't have a pipe as well in the output.

Comment: Don't store such data to begin with. Table fields are supposed to contain a *single* value. If you used a proper design you wouldn't have to split strings. If you don't need to frequently query such data, you can store it as JSON and use the JSON functions available in all supported SQL Server versions

Comment: SUBSTRING starts at 1, you also need to trim spaces presumably

Comment: A proper use for `JSON` would be to treat `url` as a bag with data that's never used for filtering and doesn't require complex logic to produce the output. `JSON_VALUE(url,'$.[0]')`` can produce the first value easily. Trying to return the first value that fulfills some criteria though, would mean the data really needs to go into its own table

Comment: will it harm the process if the substring is set to begin at positon '0'. Could you pl enlighten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to wrap the `CHARINDEX` with `NULLIF` and then the whole expression with `ISNULL`:

```
ISNULL(SUBSTRING(url, 0, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', url), 0)), url)
```

Another method would be to add a `'|'` character to the end, so there is always one in the string:

```
SUBSTRING(url, 0, CHARINDEX('|', url+'|')
```

Ideally, however, you should be fixing your design. Don't store delimited data in your database in the first place.

Comment: This wouldn't be so bad if the field contained a JSON array and was treated as a bag instead of an array of values. Eg, if there's no need to filter by URL and the extracted values are only used for output.

Comment: Don't disagree that storing JSON or XML isn't as "bad", @PanagiotisKanavos ; they have their uses. Delimited data, however, does not belong in an RDBMS, and I think we can all agree on that. :)

Comment: amazing talent! thanks for the quick turnaround time. I prefer the first soln. I find it more handy. Thanks mate